# postgresql triggers possible infinte loop?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a table with 3 fields

```
id, name , value
```

I want to add a 4th colum `calcValue`. The calculation of `calcValue` is based on  the filed `value` in the whole table, changing it in one row can cause changes in all of the others.

I want to write a trigger that updates `calcValue` everytime there is `insert, delete or update` in the table.

What i'm worry about is that the trigger itself is going to have an `Update` command. Will it case another call to this trigger? Will I be stuck with infinte loop?

To describe it better:

```
CREATE TRIGGER x
  AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE
  ON a
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE dosomething();
```

and:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dosomething()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$

begin 
        code + calculation of result...
                for row in 
                             QUERY
                Loop
             Update a set calValue=result where id=...
                end loop;
end;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

Will the update of `a` in `dosomething()` will cause another invoke of the trigger `x`? If it does is there a way to handle it so it won't stuck in infinte loop?

My goal is to do `dosomething()` once per update/insert/delete action of `a` . I don't want `dosomething()` to be called again because of the update `a` in the trigger.

**Edit:** Since i'm updating in the trigger a diffrent column I can do that:

```
CREATE TRIGGER x
    BEFORE UPDATE OF value ON a
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE dosomething();
```

this should solve my problem as the trigger updates `calcValue` and the tigger isn't set invoke on `value` column.  However I would still like to know if there is an answer to my original question... suppose that the trigger would have update the same column.

Comment: You can probably also use a `when` clause on the trigger. In the form of `when new.value <> old.value` for example.

Comment: Can you explain how will that help? I don't see the benifit of it

Comment: It will only execute the trigger when there's a change in the `value` field. Therefore when inside the trigger you update `calcValue`, the trigger is not called again, preventing an infinite "loop".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another alternative would be to add a `when` clause, along the lines of:

```
CREATE TRIGGER x
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE
ON a
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN NEW IS NULL OR OLD IS NULL OR NEW.value <> OLD.value
EXECUTE PROCEDURE dosomething();
```

It will only execute the trigger when there's a change in the value field. Therefore when inside the trigger you update `calcValue`, the trigger is not called again, preventing an infinite "loop".

Comment: How would that work? If I understand corectly that still would do uneccery calls until somepoint that nothing changes?

Comment: @user2641077 What unnecessary calls?

Comment: ho I didn't see you wrote the WHEN on `value`.

Comment: it gives an error on the word `NEW`: `ERROR: DELETE trigger's WHEN condition cannot reference NEW values`

Comment: @user2641077 Try with the new `when` clause.

Comment: i seperated it to two triggers. one for delete and one for insert and update and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You could be using `pg_trigger_depth()` to prevent this exact scenario so long as it is compliant with the broader trigger ecosystem (present and future).

```
CREATE TRIGGER my_trigger
AFTER INSERT ON my_tbl
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (pg_trigger_depth() < 1)
EXECUTE PROCEDURE my_trigger_func();
```

See https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/163142/is-pg-trigger-depth-bad-to-use-for-preventing-trigger-cascading-recursion